# How do I create Java Instant from epoch microseconds or nanoseconds?

Tags: java, timestamp

I'm trying to standardize time stamp format for my project, where the source reports in microsecond precision. I'm trying to find out whether there is a clean or minimal approach that does not require using handwritten constants.

Comment: ... Like, `Instant.ofEpochMilli()`?

Comment: The question doesn’t match the title and means nothing. Please rephrase your question to state clearly what you’re asking.

Comment: If you find the divisions/modulus complex or unreadable, why not use the `TimeUnit` enum to do the conversions for you?

Comment: I'm looking for micro and nano, not millis. I'm new to Java's suite of date time conversions so I'm not sure what's the cleanest way other than making calculations across the program.

Comment: @Slaw good suggestion. Let me try.

Comment: Would you guys mind indicating reason for downvote so that I can improve the question?

Comment: @JBNizet clarified what I mean by complex in the question

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar thanks. updated.

Comment: @Slaw I gave it a shot in the description. Let me know if you know a better way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Thanks for the suggestions. This is the cleanest I could come up with:

```java
static Instant getInstantFromMicros(long microsSinceEpoch) {
    return Instant.ofEpochSecond(
            TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toSeconds(microsSinceEpoch), 
            TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(
                    Math.floorMod(microsSinceEpoch, TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(1))
            )
    );
}

static Instant getInstantFromNanos(long nanosSinceEpoch) {
    return Instant.ofEpochSecond(0L, nanosSinceEpoch);
}
```

Test Cases:

```
System.out.println(getInstantFromMicros(1_500_000_000_123_456L));
// 2017-07-14T02:40:00.123456Z
    
System.out.println(getInstantFromNanos(1_500_000_000_123_456_789L));
// 2017-07-14T02:40:00.123456789Z
```

Comment: For the nanos IIRC you can simply do `Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, nanosSinceEpoch)`. For the micros instead of `1000_000L` I would prefer `TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMicros(1)`. Thanks for sharing your solution, I basically like it.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks let me try that suggestion. And there isn't a `Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, nanosSinceEpoch)` apparently, it's actually `Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSecond, nanoAdjustment)`

Comment: It works (for me at least): `Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, 1_500_000_000_123_456_789L)` yields `2017-07-14T02:40:00.123456789Z`, the same result you report. [The documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochSecond-long-long-) says: “This method allows an arbitrary number of nanoseconds to be passed in.”

Comment: @OleV.V. that makes sense. I verified this in JDK 11 and it works. It cleans up my solution more so I have updated my answer.

Comment: It’s become a beautiful answer, thanks. Sorry that I cannot upvote once more.

Comment: @OleV.V. maybe you can help by upvoting the question ;) Few folks didn't get it, downvoted and disappeared.

Comment: For the first function, you can just return 

`Instant.ofEpochSecond(0, TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(microsSinceEpoch))`

Comment: @ayush3504 Can't we just return `getInstantFromNanos(microsSinceEpoch * 1000L)` in `getInstantFromMicros`?

Answer (score 0):

This is simplified methods of the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56068023/330457).

```java
    static final long NANOS_PER_SECOND = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(1L);

    static final long NANOS_PER_MICROSECOND = TimeUnit.MICROSECONDS.toNanos(1L);

    /**
     * Obtains an instance of Instant using nanoseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
     *
     * @param epochNano the number of nanoseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
     * @return an instant; not {@code null}.
     */
    public static Instant instantOfEpochNano(final long epochNano) {
        return Instant.ofEpochSecond(0L, epochNano);
    }

    /**
     * Obtains an instance of Instant using microseconds from the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
     *
     * @param epochMicro the number of microseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
     * @return an instant; not {@code null}.
     * @see #instantOfEpochNano(long)
     */
    public static Instant instantOfEpochMicro(final long epochMicro) {
        return instantOfEpochNano(Math.multiplyExact(epochMicro, NANOS_PER_MICROSECOND));

    }
```